# Attribute Not Updating On PUT Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a user system set up with 2 models --> The Plans Model has_many Users.

What I would like to implement is a way to allow the users to upgrade/downgrade their plans. To do this, I've created a POST action in the controller called "update_plan", and when the user POSTs a new Plan_id to it, than the user's plan_id would change, and hence would be subscribed to a different plan.

When I POST to the Update-plan controller though the plan_id for the user does not change. I verified this by going to the console, and doing

```
user = User.find(1)
user.plan.id
```

When checking the plan_id the second time, there was no change.

Here's what my form looks like for changing the plan id

```
                       <%= form_tag("/users/update_plan", :method => "post" ) do %>

                        <%= hidden_field_tag :plan_id, plan.id %>

                        <%= submit_tag("Change To Plan", :class => "signup") %>


                      <% end %>
```

And here's the Update Plan Action, in the Users Controller

```
  def update_plan
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:plan_id])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to change_plan_path
    else
      render change_plan_path
      flash[:errors] = "Oops, something went wrong with the Update. Please Talk To Support"
    end
  end
```

I am not quite sure where the error is though, because I'm not too sure in the core I've written above.

How would you update the parameters of the user's plan_id? Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to do `@user.update_attributes(params)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@user.update_attributes(params[:plan_id])` won't update the user in the way you're expecting. `update_attributes` expects a hash which contains keys that match the model's columns names.

To update a single column, try this:

```
@user = current_user
@user.plan_id = params[:plan_id]
@user.save
```

Another way, is to pass `update_attributes` a hash with plan_id (assuming `plan_id` can be mass assigned):

```
@user.update_attributes({:plan_id => params[:plan_id]})
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the update on this. I've implemented your changes, though the change in plan_id still doesn't register.  I think there might be another problem that is preventing it from saving to the database though. It might be Submitting to the wrong Action. Your thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated